# R & Oracle - Encoding

Tags: r, oracle

Recently, I have written a piece of code in R to plot a diagram with dots which are labeled with Persian words (Persian is a right to left language). Although, I have set UTF8 for encoding and Persian_Iran.1256 for its locale, it shows Persian words inversely and separately. My system specification and R sample code are written below. Please guide me to fix this annoying problem. If I cannot fix it, I cannot use R in my researches any more. I really appreciate any guidance or opinion.

.>R.Version()

```
$platform
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "mingw32"

$system
[1] "x86_64, mingw32"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "0.1"

$year
[1] "2012"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "22"

$`svn rev`
[1] "59600"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "Oracle Distribution of R version 3.0.1 (2012-06-22)"

$nickname
[1] "Good Sport"
```

.> sessionInfo()

```
Oracle Distribution of R version 3.0.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Persian_Iran.1256  LC_CTYPE=Persian_Iran.1256    LC_MONETARY=Persian_Iran.1256
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  LC_TIME=Persian_Iran.1256 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
> .Platform
$OS.type
[1] "windows"

$file.sep
[1] "/"

$dynlib.ext
[1] ".dll"

$GUI
[1] "Rgui"

$endian
[1] "little"

$pkgType
[1] "win.binary"

$path.sep
[1] ";"

$r_arch
[1] "x64"
```

.> getOption("encoding")

```
[1] "native.enc"
```

R sample code (written in Oracle database)

```
begin
  sys.rqscriptDrop('RandomRedDots');
  sys.rqscriptcreate('RandomRedDots',
  'function(n){library(ROracle)

              u8="UTF8"
              w56="windows-1256"
              p56="Persian_Iran.1256"

#set characterset              
              Sys.setlocale(locale = p56)
              options(encoding = u8)

              drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
              con <- dbConnect(drv, username ="dfgdg", password="sdgsdg", sysdba = TRUE)

#set a persian word in R program              
              y="همه ي تراکنشها"
              y=paste(y,
                     iconv(x=y, from=u8,  to=w56),
                     iconv(x=y, from=w56, to=u8),
                     sep=" # ")

# get a persian word from Oracle database: همه ي تراکنشها
              x=dbGetQuery(con,"select t.all_trans_all_files_desc from shaparak.trans_type_dim_tab t where t.trans_id =2")

#plot an image with persian words              
              plot(1:n,rnorm(n),
                  ylab =iconv(x=x, from=u8,  to=w56) ,
                  xlab =iconv(x=x, from=w56, to=u8),
                  main=y)
              }');
end;
```

Runnig above sample code

```
select * 
 from table(rqtableeval(cursor(select 10 n from dual),
                        NULL,'PNG','RandomRedDots'));
```

Also I should mention the type of my column in oracle is varchar and my oracle characterset is AL32UTF8

Result

[image]

Regards
Parviz

Comment: thank you Roland, but as mentioned on that post, their OS was Mac or Linux and mine is Windows, furthermore I can't change our server OS.

Comment: I have wrote a function for it. ;)